# copy from another cell using a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on copying some cell values from a row into a column, yet it must fulfill one condition: there should be at least 1 E-mail after the column "emails",

E.g:

```
Name    |  First Name  |    Last Name  |emails      |           |   
john doe|       john   |    doe        | 1@me.com   |2@me.com   |3@me.com
```

Where the "|" delimits the columns of my spreadsheet.

I want to go trough each emails and copy them into a line below, so that I have 3 lines each with a different E-mail address, but with the same data (name, first name and last name)

I'm using the following code, yet, it doesn't work at all:

```
col = 1

    For i = 2 To lastrow
    emailnumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(i, Email + 1), Cells(i, lastcolumn)))
    If emailcount > 0 Then
    Cells(i + 1, Email) = Cells(i, Email + col)
    col = col + 1
    End If
    Next i

where: Email = 4
```

You're help will be highly appreciated !

Thank you in advance !

Best regards,
Ionut Sanda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick, all you have to do is sort at the end:

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng1 As Range, rngMail As Range, lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng1 = Range("A2:C" & lastRow)
    Set rngMail = Range("D2:D" & lastRow)
    Union(rng1, rngMail.Offset(0, 1)).Copy Range("A" & lastRow + 1)
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Union(rng1, rngMail.Offset(0, 2)).Copy Range("A" & lastRow + 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, this solved my issue ! Thank you very much for the prompt answer!

Comment: You're welcome. Now you should mark this answer as Accepted